# Jquery - adjust border-radius for a tabbed content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following tabbed content in my site which has border radius around it . The problem is when the first tab is selected the border radius near it still exists and doesn't make it seem good.

[image]

I wrote a piece of jquery to fix it but when it removes the radius, doesn't bring it back when the tab is not selected anymore.

```
    if (tab_id=="tab-1"){
        $('.tab-content').css("border-top-right-radius","0");
    }
    if (tab_id!=="tab-1"){
        $('.tab-content').css("border-top-right-radius","5px;");
    }
```

any ideas please??

ps : 
[this](https://codepen.io/cssjockey/pen/jGzuK)
is what i'm working on . except i also want the .tab-content to have a border radius of 5pixels.

Comment: `=` is an assignment, `==` is a comparison.

Comment: Thank you Mikey, but it changed nothing

Comment: You need to make a Minimum Complete Viable Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - a picture isn't enough. What @Mikey pointed out is revealing. You can put one together in a stack snippet or jsFiggle or codepen or whatever... the least amount of code needed to show the issue. I'll make one for you - but next time, it's all you. : )

Comment: What's `tab_id`? Post the rest of your code please.

Comment: You know you can use an if / else if statement instead of two if statements? Also, if you're using `==` to compare id's then use `!=` to check if they're not the same, as opposed to `!==`.

Comment: Try getting an outline of what you've tried and a basic scenario going like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/ckv0f9ax/

Comment: I added a link on Codepen . hope it helps...

Comment: sheriffderek : this is what i have now. I want the top left and top right  border radius be removed when the tab next to it is selected so they look as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for an if statement that checks if the tab selected is the first child. If the statement returns true, then it sets `border-radius` to 5px on `.tab-content` on all sides except the top left. If false, then it sets `border-radius` to 5px on all sides.

This if/else statement needs to be called twice in the code. Once before the `.click()` function, and one inside it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".tab-link.current").is(":first-child")) {
    $(".tab-content").css("border-radius", "0 5px 5px 5px");
  } else {
    $(".tab-content").css("border-radius", "5px");
  }
  $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr("data-tab");

    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("current");
    $(".tab-content").removeClass("current");

    $(this).addClass("current");
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass("current");
    if ($(".tab-link.current").is(":first-child")) {
      $(".tab-content").css("border-radius", "0 5px 5px 5px");
    } else {
      $(".tab-content").css("border-radius", "5px");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.tabs li {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tabs li.current {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
    Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>

</div>
<!-- container -->
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/AquatuzMagnus/pen/QgdaoM)

Answer (score 0):

Well you simply need to create a class

```
.roundBorder{
  border-top-right-radius:15px;
}
```

And then simply use `addClass()` when tab is clicked

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');

        //add this line to add rounded border on tab click           
        $(this).addClass('roundBorder');

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try like this?

```
        $('ul.nav li a').filter(function () {
            if (this.id == 'tab_1') {
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            }
            else
             {$(this).parent().removeClass('active'); }
        });
    });
```

And here is active class

```
 .active{
          border-top-right-radius:10px;
         }
```